# how to sort word of a string by number value

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this problem:

"Your task is to sort a given string. Each word in the string will contain a single number. This number is the position the word should have in the result.

Note: Numbers can be from 1 to 9. So 1 will be the first word (not 0).

If the input string is empty, return an empty string. The words in the input String will only contain valid consecutive numbers.

Examples: "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"  -->  "Thi1s is2 3a T4est"

I tried to first split the string that I received and then use the sort() function but I think that is ordering the sentence by the size of each word rather by the number in them.

```py
def order(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    words.sort()
    return words

print(order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"))
```

It should order the sentence like this "Thi1s is2 3a T4est" but my code sort the sentence like this ['3a', 'T4est', 'Thi1s', 'is2']

Comment: Yep, your code is sorting the words by their lexicographical ("dictionary") ordering. You'll need a key function that can find the number in each word, and use that.

Comment: Since this is very likely homework, you might not get a full-on solution. Nudges in the right direction like the above comment are where you should start.

Comment: As AKX mentioned, you need to pass something to the `key` argument of sorted and that needs to be a function that can extract only the number from each of your words. Once you have that, the answer is `sorted(words, key=get_number_from_word)`. Have a go at creating that `get_number_from_word` function. For example `get_number_from_word("T4est")` should return `"4"` or `4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function version:

```
sentence = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"

def order(sentence):
    # creates a tuple of (int, word) for each word in the sentence
    # we need a nested listed comprehension to iterate each letter in the word
    # [... for w in sentence.split() ...] -> for each word in the sentence
    # [... for l in w ...] -> for each letter in each word
    # [... if l.isdigit()] -> if the letter is a digit
    # [(int(l), w) ...] -> add a tuple of (int(letter), word) to the final list
    words = [(int(l), w) for w in sentence.split() for l in w if l.isdigit()]
    words.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])
    return " ".join(t[1] for t in words)

print(order(sentence))

>>> Thi1s is2 3a T4est
```

Here's a fun one-liner

```
sentence = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"
new = " ".join(t[1] for t in sorted([(int(l), w) for w in sentence.split() for l in w if l.isdigit()], key=lambda t: t[0]))
print(new)

>>> Thi1s is2 3a T4est
```

Comment: Which part @RaúlSantamaría? I'll add some info to the answer

Comment: @RaúlSantamaría don't be tempted by a one liner. It detracts from readability, which is very important.

Comment: the whole thing, but especially this [(int(l), w) for w in sentence.split() for l in w if l.isdigit()]

Comment: @RaúlSantamaría added some comments explaining the different parts of that

Comment: Dan is right that you shouldn't use a one liner in real code, but it's helpful to explore more advanced python syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't going to post an answer as this sounds like homework.

That said, there are other answers that aren't as clear/readable. I've kept list expansion out of this example for readability.

```
def order(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    ordered_words = sorted(words, key=int_from_word)
    return " ".join(ordered_words)

def int_from_word(word):
    for character in word:
        if character.isdigit():
            return int(character)
    return None

print(order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"))
```

Output:

```
Thi1s is2 3a T4est
```

Comment: This is the most clear solution. @JimWright you should add a `" ".join` to `order` for completeness

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you can split each word in the sentence into characters.

```py
def order(sentence):
    indices=[]
    words=[]
    for word in sentence.split():
        letters=[letter for letter in word]
        for letter in letters:
            try:
                indices+=[int(letter)-1]
            except:
                pass
    output=[]
    for index in indices:
        output+=[sentence.split()[index]]
    return output
```

If you want the output to be a string you can change the return statement:

```py
return " ".join(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, commented the process line by line:

```py
def order(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    ### extract the number from the string (single word)
    nums = [ int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x))) for x in words ]
    ### pair the number to the word
    dictionary = dict(zip(nums, words))
    ### sort based on the number extracted
    sorted_x = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0])
    ### take only word (and not number coupled)
    result = [ x[1] for x in sorted_x ]
    return result

print(order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"))
### output:
['Thi1s', 'is2', '3a', 'T4est']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex and `sort()` since no one has done that already:

```
import re

s = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"
words = s.split()

myre = re.compile(r'\d+')
words.sort(key=lambda x: myre.findall(x))

print(' '.join(words))
```

Since the OP has a thing for one liners (this is less efficient and less readable):

```
import re

s = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"
new = ' '.join(sorted(s.split(), key=lambda x: re.findall(r'\d+', x)))
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a homework question so I am posting the simplest way I could solve it.

```
def find_number(word): #returns the number present in the string
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if(word[i].isdigit()):
            num=""
            while(i<len(word) and word[i].isdigit()):
                num+=word[i]
                i+=1
            return int(num)
def order(sentence):
    od={}
    ct="a"
    for i in sentence.split():
        #numbering the strings so that if there are duplicates they are not lost
        od[ct+i]=find_number(i)
        ct=chr(ord(ct)+1)
    for i in sorted(od.values()):
        for j in od: #we can use other way of printing but this is the simplest but way less efficient
            if (od[j]==i):
                print(j[1:])
                break
s=input()
order(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

s ="outp4ut Thi1s 3an st5ring i2s"

d = collections.defaultdict()

for word in s.split():
    for char in word:   # itertaing through the characters of the word
        if char.isdigit():  
            d[int(char)] = word  # adding char to the dictionary if the char is a digit
            break
       
values_arr = []

for num in sorted(d.keys()): # sort the keys
    values_arr.append(d[num])

output = " ".join(values_arr)   

print(output)

### output: Thi1s i2s 3an outp4ut st5ring
```

Answer (score 0):

def order(sentence):
words = sentence.split()
ordered_words = sorted(words, key=int_from_word)
return " ".join(ordered_words)

def int_from_word(word):
for character in word:
if character.isdigit():
return int(character)
return None

print(order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).